# Lines on object - unexplained

Tags: objects, wireframe

[image]I am coming towards my first render, expect there is a problem, and I do not know why. I do not know what the lines are.

[image]

Comment: Hello, Saima, please share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ . 2 Things spring to mind.. there is a bump-map / other shader affecting the appearance.. or there is an object set to render, but hidden in the viewport.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!I tried to upload the file but the original file was above 30MB (82.3MB) so I have deleted objects. It’s my first time using the application so keen to understand why this is happening. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Comment: Hi. Sorry I misunderstood. I have added the blender exchange link to the original post. Many thanks

Comment: To analyze this with you material you'll have to re-post the file, with *File >> External Data >> Pack Resources*.  To trim down your file size, perhaps in your posted copy you can delete objects are are not part of your focus.